# '&' sign before function name in PHP

Tags: php

Can you please explain to me the differences between two functions:

```
function &a(){
    return something;
}
```

and

```
function b(){
    return something;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first returns a reference to `something`, the second a copy of `something`.

In first case, when the caller modify the returned value, `something` will be modified as a global variable do.

In the second case, modifying a copy as no effect to the source.

Answer (score 0):

An ampersand before a function name means the **function will return a reference to a variable instead of the value**.

According to this [**LINK**](https://www.php.net/references.return)

```
Returning by reference is useful when you want to use a function to find to which     
variable a reference should be bound. Do not use return-by-reference to increase 
performance. The engine will automatically optimize this on its own. Only return 
references when you have a valid technical reason to do so.
```